# Scrapy Form submission with html select not working

Tags: python, scrapy

I have to simulate the form submission in scrapy to generate a page.

Following is the form (i cut little parts)

```
<form id="" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST" action="#">
<fieldset>
<div class="select-style">
<select id="study-select" name="">
<option>Choose an area of study</option>
<option data-tag="a1">Anthropology</option>
<option data-tag="a2">Architecture</option>
<option data-tag="b1">Biology</option>
<option data-tag="b2">Botany</option>
...
</select>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I am writing the following code in scrapy. My form xpath is correct. I am testing code in scrapy shell to be sure.

```
resfrom = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, 
formxpath='//div[@id="field_switcher"]//form', 
formdata={'study-select':'Biology'}, 
clickdata={'type':'submit'}, method= 'POST')
```

But this is not working. I just cant "post" this. 
Subsequently writing `resfrom.body'` just gives `'study-select=Biology'`.
How to "post" data to a field with id in scrapy? I have tried many options but nothing seems to work. What problem you see in my code.

Comment: Could you provide the URL to this page?

Comment: Thanks. http://www.apple.com/retail/storelist/ 
I changed it a bit. :)

Comment: first of all your form example has no `id` (`id=""`, and the site you shared doesn't contain that form either

Comment: @eLRuLL it is there. Inspect in firbug the country input element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, *there is no form to submit*. Data is already there in the HTML.

Here is sample code to group the store locations by country:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.apple.com/retail/storelist/
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>>
>>> data = {}
>>> for country in response.css(".section-country-stores .listing"):
...     country_id = country.xpath("@id").extract_first().replace("stores", "")
...     data[country_id] = [" ".join(map(unicode.strip, place.xpath(".//li//text()").extract())) for place in country.css("ul")]
... 
>>> pprint(data)
{u'ae': [u'Abu Dhabi, Yas Mall Yas Mall Yas Island Abu Dhabi 800 04441824',
         u'Dubai, Mall of the Emirates Mall of the Emirates Al Barsha 1 Dubai 800 04441819'],
 u'au': [u'Canberra Canberra Centre Canberra ACT 2601 (02) 6224 9500',
         u'Bondi 213 Oxford Street Bondi Junction NSW 2022 (02) 9019 2400',
         ...
         ],
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. I could get data without submitting form. But what if i want to submit form. I mean selecting a country does change the display of the page. what if i want to access that thing. I might be wrong. If the form does not submit then why is it there. I am learning scrapy from some help material and I was thinking how to simulate the form submission on this page.

Comment: @mkike according the browser developer tools, selecting a country does not issue any network requests, meaning there is no form submission..

Comment: Yes i inspected that. So it is just calling script to change display right? And this thing can not be "simulated"?

Comment: @mkike well, not with Scrapy, it is not a browser and does not have a js engine built-in. You can look into `selenium` to simulate it.